# PHP and Oracle Session Login

Tags: php, oracle11g

Here it's I have a problem with my PHP Code + Oracle Login form.
In this PHP file, I make login function. But I have an error like this :

```
    Warning: oci_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\developers\it\session.php on line 12
Wrong
```

-

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("config.php");
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$do = $_GET['do'];
if($do=="login")
{
    $cek = "SELECT PASSWORD, USER_LEVEL FROM T_USERS WHERE USERNAME='$username' AND PASSWORD='$password'";
    $result = oci_parse($conn, $cek);
    oci_execute($result);
    if(oci_num_rows($cek)==1)
    {
        $c = oci_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $c['username']; ociresult($c,"USERNAME");
        $_SESSION['USER_LEVEL'] = $c['USER_LEVEL']; ociresult($c,"USER_LEVEL");
        if($c['USER_LEVEL']=="ADMINISTRATOR")
        {
            header("location:supervisor.php");
        }
        else if($c['user_level']=="User")
        {
            header("location:user.php");
        }
        else if($c['user_level']=="Root")
        {
            header("location:administrator.php");
        }
        else if($c['user_level']=="Manager")
        {
            header("location:manager.php");
        }
        else if($c['user_level']=="Admin")
        {
            header("location:admin.php");
        }
        else if($c['user_level']=="Director")
        {
            header("location:director.php");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Wrong";
    }
}
?>
```

I have tried to search in google, but still don't find anything.
Someone knows, what's the problem ?
Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to your script instead of

```
if(oci_num_rows($cek)==1)
```

you should call

```
if(oci_num_rows($result)==1)
```

Comment: for wrong login, that's true. But when I try to login using correct login, it still give an message "Wrong". Any Help again ?

Comment: `var_dump(oci_fetch_array($result))` and check

Comment: it show error like this : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\developers\it\session.php on line 16

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `$result` and not `$cek` when you're asking for the number of rows returned from `oci_num_rows()`. However, you *really* want to avoid using `$username` and `$password` directly in the string like that. It'll make you wide open for SQL injection attacks, so look into using `oci_parse` together with [oci_bind_by_name](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php).

After that you should also always call `exit()` after the sequence of redirects, as the script will continue running if you don't (and that might be a security issue other places).

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same case, so I tricked it with a script like this, but I don't know whether there was an impact or not. because the session and validation went smoothly.

```
    $username =$_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $conn = oci_connect('xxx', 'xxx', 'localhost/MYDB');
    $pass_encription = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * from *table_name* WHERE *field1*='".$username."' and *field2*='".$password."'";
    $result = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    oci_execute($result);
    $exe = oci_fetch($result);
     if ($exe > 0)
     {
        oci_close($conn);
        oci_execute($result);
        $row        =oci_fetch_array($result);

        $sid        = $row['field_1_parameter'];
        $snama      = $row['field_2_parameter'];
        $sjab       = $row['field_3_parameter'];

        $session    = array     ( 
                                    'field_1_array'             =>$sid,
                                    'field_2_array'             =>$snama,
                                    'field_3_array'             =>$sjab 
                                );

        if($sjab == 'Administrator')
            {
                $this->session->set_userdata($session);
                redirect('redirecting_page');
            }
```

`